# Angular Karma unit test with multiple digest cycles

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a watch on my CRUD object person and I have watches on my select objects. In my unit test I want the initalization of the person object to initialize the select objects and I want changes in the select objects to change the person object. My unit test is failing because I unable to run two digest cycles in one test. Which means that all the changes in person and the select objects are processed at the same time overwriting one or the other. Please help.

```
scope.person = samplePersonPutData;
scope.$apply();
scope.selects.medicalConditions.values.push({id:'02', text:'Cold'});
scope.selects.courses.values = [];
scope.selects.nextOfKin.value = {id:'1111111112', text:'Bob'};
scope.$apply(); //this doesn't run

$httpBackend.expectPUT(/people\/([0-9a-fA-F]{24})$/,samplePersonPutResponse).respond();

scope.update();
$httpBackend.flush();
```

Comment: What do u mean by 'this doesn't run'? Are getting any error?

Comment: I mean that the command does nothing. No watches are fired.

Comment: Can you share the source code which this test is supposed be testing. Are you certain that its just test code issue?

Comment: My similar create unit test works, since the person object is null in that case only one digest cycle is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code that this is testing are objects that hold the select opts and values, it is as follows :

```
function TagSelect(baseObj, sub, field, tags, $scope){
    Select2.call(this, sub, field);
    console.log("TagSelect Constructing "+baseObj+","+sub+","+field);
    this.tags = tags;
    this.scope = $scope;

    this.opts = {
            initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                callback(element);
            },
            multiple: true,
            tags: function() {
                return tags;
            },
            width: '100%'
        };

    this.values = [];
    this.new = '';
    this.baseObj = baseObj;

    this.scope.$watch('selects.'+this.field+'.values',this.selectWatch(this, this.baseObj)); 

    this.scope.unwatchBaseObj = this.scope.$watch(baseObj, this.baseObjWatch(this));


}

TagSelect.prototype = Object.create(Select2.prototype);

TagSelect.prototype.constructor = TagSelect;

TagSelect.prototype.selectWatch = function(self, objectName){
    return function(){
        self.setDO(objectName);
    };
};

TagSelect.prototype.baseObjWatch = function(self){
    return function(){
        self.setValue(self.scope[self.baseObj]);
        console.log('watch baseObj self.field:'+self.field);
    };
};  

TagSelect.prototype.setDO = function(baseObj){
    var i;
    if(this.values.length === 0)return;

    //var watchers = this.scope.$$watchers;
    //this.scope.$$watchers = [];

    console.log("setting DO for "+this.field+" values.length"+this.values.length);
    if(!this.scope[baseObj]){
        this.scope[baseObj] = {};
    }
    if(this.sub){
        if(!this.scope[baseObj][this.sub]){
            this.scope[baseObj][this.sub] = {};
        }
        this.scope[baseObj][this.sub][this.field] = [];
        for(i = 0; i < this.values.length; i++){
            this.scope[baseObj][this.sub][this.field].push(this.values[i].text);
        }
    }else{
        this.scope[baseObj][this.field] = [];
        for(i = 0; i < this.values.length; i++){
            this.scope[baseObj][this.field].push(this.values[i].text);
        }

    }

    //this.scope.$$watchers = watchers;
};

TagSelect.prototype.setValue = function(object){
    var i;
    console.log("in setValue");

    //var watchers = this.scope.$$watchers;
    //this.scope.$$watchers = [];

    //this.scope.unwatchBaseObj();
    if(this.sub){
        console.log("setting select for "+this.field);
        if(object[this.sub] && object[this.sub][this.field]){
            this.values = [];
            console.log("setting select for "+this.field+" with length:"+object[this.sub][this.field].length+" values.length:"+this.values.length);

            for(i = 0; i < object[this.sub][this.field].length; i++){
                this.values.push({id: object[this.sub][this.field][i], text: object[this.sub][this.field][i]});
            }   
        }
    }else{
        if(object[this.field]){
            this.values = [];
            console.log("setting select for "+this.field+" with length:"+object[this.field].length);

            for(i = 0; i < object[this.field].length; i++){
                this.values.push({id: object[this.field][i], text: object[this.field][i]});
            }   
        }

    }

    //this.scope.$$watchers = watchers;
};
```